# node js polling data changes

Tags: node.js, redis, polling

Using node js with redis as a cache and pub-sub code. The cache stores list of useful messages. After a point, the messages are deleted from redis. If the number of messages falls below 10, we have to 'publish' a response to all the subscribers to consume and perform some action.

Here is my draft publisher code:

```
var redis = require('redis')    
var pub = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost');

pub.keys('message:*', function (err, keys){
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  if (keys.length < 10){

    pub.publish("mchannel", "Messages threshold reached", function(err){
        if (err) throw err;            
    });
  }

});
```

Subscriber code:

```
var redis = require('redis')
var sub = redis.createClient();

sub.on("message", function(channel, message){
  console.log("Message '" + message + "' on channel '" + channel + "'  received!")
  // Some action...
});
sub.subscribe("mchannel");
```

When i execute the publisher and subscriber code using the node command, the message is published only once..as expected.

How can i constantly poll for cache changes from the publisher code and publish that message?

Comment: well, you would have to repeatedly check for data, or, check the length every time an action occurs that would change the data.

Comment: Should i use an infinite loop inside the function and check for it? Please advise.

Comment: I guess that depends on what you consider an infinite loop. To me, `while (true) { do() }` would be an infinite loop, and that'd be a bad idea. I would just use a setInterval or a scheduling module such as agenda set to run once per minute.

Comment: yeah, not going to post code snippets.